# How to use aliases in Google Calendar?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have a google account (say hellome@gmail.com) that is set up to send mail for many other accounts (hellome@mydomain.com, secondaccount@gmail.com...).

For at least one of those accounts (hellome@mydomain.com) google will not let me set up a separate google account. It says there is an existing account and that it is disabled. Perhaps this is because it is already connected to a gmail account.

I want to create google calendar events as 'hellome@mydomain.com', that is to have 'hellome@mydomain.com' show up in the 'created by' field for an event instead of 'hellome@gmail.com'.

This is important because, in creating events for work I do not want my personal email to show up. Is there a way to switch email accounts, hide or change the 'created by' field in Google Calendar? Any help or suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, it is not possible. Google are ignoring the hundreds of people having the same issues. We just cancelled our Google Apps for Business account solely because of this feature not being available.

We, just as every other business out there, do not want to use the personal name@company.com when sending a google calendar event to a customer, but instead from an alias like sales@company.com

Comment: Google eliminated the only workaround that I've found, which was to create a separate Gmail calendar with the business email account. It now requires users to have a gmail.com account as the primary email address, and that's what shows up on the calendar invites.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible.

1. set up a google account with your alternative email address and
2. alter the calendar settings to share its calendar with your main google account
3. choose that calendar when making new meetings from the drop down box.

Comment: This process no longer works. Google requires users to establish a primary "gmail.com" email address, and even if you have an alternate address in your account, the Gmail.com version will appear in calendar invitations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this by,

1. Creating the sales@ as a mailbox instead of an alias.
2. Then grant your name@, full create/amend/edit rights to the mailbox and calendar for the sales@ account

You could also create a group in GSuite (even with only 1 person in) and allow the Group to manage the sales@ mailbox and calendar.

Comment: Does it require to create another user to GSuite?

Answer (score 0):

I am also a user of GSuite and I have tried many things, but it seems we need to add a new user indeed (4 Euro extra a month to pay).

BR,

Richard.