# Is there any way to set up google calendar such that invites come from an alias?

Tags: google-calendar-api, alias

I use google calendar, but I send emails from an alias email there. When I send out calendar invites, it says it comes from my google email address. Is there any way to have this sent out "coming from" the alias email address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google Calendar does not have a way to edit the email from where the invites are being sent. The invitation will only come from the primary email address.

It is a feature that has been requested for years as I was able to find a thread about the matter. Check [How to use aliases in Google Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939194/how-to-use-aliases-in-google-calendar)

I always suggest to submit a feature idea through the Google Workspace if you have: [Feature idea](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762?hl=en)!

Comment: Submitting Feature idea is hard.

"This is a closed group hub. Read the directions below to send a request to join.
Access to the Google Workspace Feature Ideas area of GCC is restricted to Corporate, Enterprise, EDU customers, or customers under NDA.

Please allow up to 1 - 2 business days for review.

You will receive a private message upon approval or denial of your access request"

Comment: As alternative you can create a ticket here :https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have shared the calendar from the alias google account with your main google account so that both calendars show up on the main.

When creating a new event, there you should see a calendar icon.  It should have a list of the "Shared Calendars".    From here select the one you want the invite sent from and it will be sent on behalf of that alias account.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHxN8.png)

Comment: Could you please clarify how to do the first part of your answer, "make sure you have shared the calendar from the alias google account with your main google account so both calendars show up..." I have an alias google email, but can't figure out how to "share the calendar" for it...thanks!

Comment: @m.arthur Within your "alias" Google calendar, go to Settings and then scroll down to "Share with Specific People" and share with your "primary" account.

Comment: How do you set up a calendar for an alias?

Comment: This anwer does not accomplish the goal of having the email containing the calendar invite come From: the aliased email address.  This answer accomplishes the nearby but different goal of having multiple, labeled calendars.   With multiple, labeled calendars one can control what set of calendar events are included (ie, in a shared calendar) but not the account the invites appear from in invitees inboxes.